# Positioning of HTML elements

Tags: html, css, positioning

HTML page:

FIRST ELEMENT

The onclick function of FIRST ELEMENT (which is < h1 >) has the following function:

```
function insert(event)
    {
        elem = document.getElementById("first");
        element = document.createElement("div");
        element2 = document.createElement("a");
        element2.href = "www.google.com";
        element2.innerHTML = "GOOGLE" + n;
        element.appendChild(element2);
        //element.innerHTML = "text content";
        element.style.position = "relative";
        element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        element.style.left = "10px";
        element.style.top = "30px";
        elem.appendChild(element);
        //document.body.appendChild(element);
        event.target.appendChild(element);
        n++;
    }
```

on clicking the 'FIRST ELEMENT' two times the output is:

```
FIRST ELEMENT

GOOGLE1

GOOGLE2
```

but I want the output to be:

```
FIRST ELEMENT

GOOGLE2

GOOGLE1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [insertBefore](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_insertbefore.asp) to rearrange the order of an elements children.
Here is what you want:

```
var n = 1;
function myfunc(event)
{
    elem = document.getElementById("first");
    element = document.createElement("div");
    element2 = document.createElement("a");
    element2.href = "www.google.com";
    element2.innerHTML = "GOOGLE" + n;
    element.appendChild(element2);
    element.style.position = "relative";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    element.style.left = "10px";
    element.style.top = "30px";
    elem.appendChild(element);

    children = elem.children;         

    if(typeof(children) != "undefined" && children.length > 1){

        num = children.length - 1;
        elem.insertBefore(children[num], children[1]);
    }

    n++;
}​
```

Link to working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/szNcT/